# C# error about missing "out" parameter, but the code works fine

Tags: c#, parameters, visual-studio-code, out

I have a C# project that contains a method that looks something like this:

```
bool TheMethod(Type arg, out Type output)
```

And then it's called later on in the file, it looks something like this, with only one argument:

```
if (TheMethod(someArgument))
```

And VS Code reports this error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
>   parameter 'output' of 'TheMethod(Type, out Type)' (CS7036) [Managed]

Despite this error, the code compiles and runs fine. What's going on? Is this a problem with code validation? Is the out parameter required in some cases, but not others? Should I edit the code so that it outputs to a local field, even if I won't ever use it?

The actual code can be found here: https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/master/modules/mono/glue/Managed/Files/MarshalUtils.cs#L156

Comment: what method are you calling?

Comment: CS7036 is a *compiler* error, it cannot possibly be compiling and running.

Comment: Maybe you're running an older compiled version from before you introduced the error?

Comment: @itsme86 most likely.. there are no optional _out parameters_ in c#

Comment: It should be `if (!GenericIDictionaryIsAssignableFromType(dictionary.GetType(), out Type output))`

Comment: That code you link to is wrapped in a compiler directive that means it will not compile in debug mode. It should work in release configuration though.

Comment: Note also that code was added 4 days ago so it just broken and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean the method:

```
static bool GenericIDictionaryIsAssignableFromType(Type type, out Type keyType, out Type valueType)
```

and the call to the method:

```
#if DEBUG
            if (!GenericIDictionaryIsAssignableFromType(dictionary.GetType()))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The type does not implement IDictionary<,>");
#endif
```

Then the behavior you are seeing is likely linked to the existence of the preprocessor directives (#if/#endif).  If you're compiling the code locally in DEBUG mode,

[image: Debug Compiler Setting]

the code will throw a compiler error of the sort you're seeing.  However, if you compile/run in RELEASE mode (which may be how your CI/CD and/or other test environments may be configured) the code will not have any errors (as the #if/#endif excludes the relevant lines of code from the file before the compiler sees them) and it will run as expected.

Comment: Thank you, this is correct. The problem I was having is that I was building the project with our own `target=debug`, but this doesn't enable the `DEBUG` directive in C#... very confusing!